# Is it pythonic to use environment variables for path export?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am developing a utility that needs to work on a specific folder.
We would like that an environment variable can set this folder, such as:

```
def get_config_path():
    return os.environ.get('MY_UTILITY_PATH', os.getcwd())
```

In the end, when the user is running: `my_utility --output /path/to/output`, I just modify the environment variable according to the argument: `os.environ['MY_UTILITY_PATH'] = self.output`.

Therefore, my functions are clearly not pure, and I am wondering if such implementation is clumsy or not. Is there a better way to operate?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round. Set `self.output` to the environment variable, if it is not set:

```
if not self.output:
    self.output = os.environ.get('MY_UTILITY_PATH', os.getcwd())
```

Comment: But in this case, I have to transmit `self.output` everywhere. So my question is more: "is it okay to use an environment variable for indicating the path?"